# Comparing integral with a sum

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation

> Show that \begin{equation}\sum_{m=1}^k\frac{1}{m}>\log k.\end{equation}

My intuition here is that the LHS looks a lot like $\int_1^k\frac{1}{x}\textrm{d}x$, and this evaluates to $\log k$. To justify why the sum is larger, note that $1/m$ is convex, and my understanding is that more generally, \begin{equation}\sum_{m=1}^kf(m)>\int_1^kf(x)\textrm{d}x\end{equation}when $f$ is convex (and of course integrable!), and that the reverse inequality holds when $f$ is concave. Is this actually correct?

I know that $\sum_{m=1}^k\frac{1}{m}-\log k\to\gamma$, the Euler-Mascheroni constant, but without prior knowledge of this I wasn't sure how to approach this problem. I am interested in a more general way to compare discrete sums with their integral counterparts.

Comment: @fGDu94 this is what I did when coming to my conclusions, but it isn't rigorous enough to constitute a proof sadly. I was interested if there was a more general theory about it

Comment: The logarithm is concave and the crucial part for the intended proof is monotonicity. It's important that $1/x$ is monotonus (in this case decreasing), not that it's convex. There's no all too general way, but if you're happy with monotonous functions (which is enough for many problems by splitting the function domain), I happen to have an idea.

Comment: In answer to your last sentence, check out the "Euler Maclaurin" summation formula on Wikipedia or elsewhere.  It provides a general way to link integrals and sums with a specific expression for error terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll show the following result and leave the result for decreasing functions and other domains to the OP.

**CLAIM:** Let $f:\mathbb R_{\ge 0}\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be increasing. Then we have $\sum_{k=0}^K f(k)\le\int_0^{K+1} f(x)\mathrm dx$ for all $K\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$.

Recall that integrability is not an issue as discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2989242/1096797).
Using that $\int_k^{k+1}\mathrm dx=1$ for all $k\in\mathbb R$, we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^K f(k)=\sum_{k=0}^K\int_{k}^{k+1}f(k)\mathrm dx.$$
Since $f$ is increasing, we know that $f(k)\le f(x)$ for $k\le x\le k+1$ and thereby
$$\sum_{k=0}^K f(k)\le\sum_{k=0}^K\int_{k}^{k+1}f(x)\mathrm dx.$$
Now, we can compose the integrals (this can also be formalized with indicator functions) to obtain
$$\sum_{k=0}^K f(k)\le\sum_{k=0}^K\int_{k}^{k+1}f(x)\mathrm dx=\int_{k=0}^{K+1}f(x)\mathrm dx.$$

This concludes the proof. The case $K=\infty$ is a bit more tricky on the formal side. If you need this to be covered, too, let me know. Also, if you need a picture illustrating the proof, let me know.

Comment: One technical issue: the problem asks for a strict inequality. This (well-written!) answer doesn't address that. In my answer I use the "almost everywhere" condition to work around this (since the strict inequality isn't true for the functions in question), and you might make some edits to fill in that gap.

Comment: The question is not overly specific, what I presented is a more general way to compare sums with their integral counterparts. If a proof for a strict inequality and, say, strictly increasing functions is required, well, I have an idea. Or any increasing function which is not right continuous and constant between integers :-)

Answer (score 0):

For any interval $[m,m+1]$, you can hopefully prove that $\frac{1}{m} > \frac{1}{x}$ for almost all $x \in [m,m+1]$. Then you can define a piecewise function $$f(x) = \frac{1}{m} \text{ if $x \in [m,m+1]$}.$$
Clearly then $f(x) > \frac{1}{x}$ for almost all $x \in [1,k]$. Moreover, $\frac{1}{m} = \int_{m}^{m+1}f(x)dx$ for all $m$. Therefore,
$$\sum_{m=1}^{k} \frac{1}{m} = \sum_{m=1}^{k} \int_{m}^{m+1}f(x)dx > \sum_{m=1}^{k-1} \int_{m}^{m+1}f(x)dx.$$
(Note the change of upper indices!)
Since $f$ is a sufficiently nice function, we have
$$\sum_{m=1}^{k-1} \int_{m}^{m+1}f(x)dx = \int_{1}^{k} f(x) dx$$
and by the fact that $f(x) > \frac{1}{x}$ almost everywhere, we should get
$$\sum_{m=1}^{k} \frac{1}{m} = \int_{1}^{k}f(x)dx > \int_{1}^{k}\frac{1}{x} dx = \log(k) - \log(1) = \log(k).$$

Comment: There are some minor issues in your proof. We have $f(x)\ge 1/x$ for $m\le x\le m+1$. In the second display, the sum goes up to $k$, because the sum on the left does, otherwise equality does not hold. The fact that the integral goes to $k$ is due to the fact that we cut the last part, we could get a stronger inequality with $\log(k+1)$.

Comment: Oh shoot! You're right. Thanks for pointing that out. Of course that's true. Silly me.

Comment: The statement about $f(x) > 1/x$ was given for *almost all* $x$ in the interval, so I believe that shouldn't be an issue. (Correct me if I'm wrong there though—honestly, it's been a bit since I've used the words "almost everywhere" and I'm in a rush.)

Comment: True, I'm sorry, I misread your first display! The function $f$ is defined, say, on $\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$. I only realized that now.